# Как соединить клиент и сервер по локальной сети без лишнего гемороя?

Tags: wcf

Я не давно начал изучать WCF и понял, как соединять клиент и сервер на одном компьютере, что, конечно, не прокатит, если клиент и сервер будут на разных компах, но подключены к одному модему. Как это реализовать без IIS? Просто сейчас любая игра имеет возможность запустить локальный сервер хоть с калькулятора, без посторонних служб, типа IIS. Да и мне надо, чтоб сервером мог стать любой комп, а не только тот, на котором он писался (если здесь дело только в IP в адресе, то это я приблизительно понимаю, как сделать).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, подойдет [Self-hosted WCF](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application).
Но придется решать вопрос о том, как клиентам и серверам узнавать друг о друге.